# MySQL struggling with a query to find similar details among products

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to write and I am absolutely stumped on how to do it.  Here's my situation, I am trying to provide a particular product_ID, then match all of the other product_IDs in the database that have at least the same intDescription_detail_IDs as the provided product_ID.

The relevant tables look like this:

**tblproducts**

```
=========================

product_ID | product_name

=========================

| 1    |    dresser  |
| 2    |    bookcase | 
| 3    |    table    |
| 4    |    chair    |

=========================
```

**tbldescriptions**

```
=========================================================================

|description_ID| intDescription_product_ID | intDescription_detail_ID   |

=========================================================================

|   1      |        1      |        1       |
|   2      |        1      |        2       |
|   4      |        2      |        1       |
|   5      |        2      |        2       |
|   6      |        2      |        6       |
|   7      |        3      |        1       |
|   8      |        3      |        3       |
|   9      |        3      |        4       |
|   10     |        4      |        1       |
|   11     |        4      |        2       |
|   12     |        4      |        7       |
```

As an example, if I provided the product_ID "1", then I would like to return all of the product_IDs that at least have intDescription_detail_ID 1 and 2.

So, the product_IDs that should be returned are 1, 2, and 4, because all of these products have the intDescription_detail_ID of 1 and 2 among their details.

I am highly confused about how to write a query like this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: And so what have you tried?

Comment: I think you need to explain what exactly it is you want slightly more!

Comment: No. The explanation is adequate - but I'd like to see an attempt at solving it!

Comment: Two questions...
`1. Why is 4 returned, if the product_ID = 1`
`2. If 4 (product_id or descript_id) is returned why not 7 and 10?`

Comment: I am not sure if I am going in the right direction but I am trying to do this with subqueries, something along the lines of   

SELECT intDescription_product_ID
FROM tbldescriptions
WHERE intDescription_detail_ID=ANY (SELECT intDescription_detail_ID
FROM tbldescriptions
WHERE intDescription_product_ID=1)
GROUP BY intDescription_product_ID

Comment: @mrdnk Product 4 shares all of product 1's attributes

Comment: 1) product_ID 4 is returned among the results because there is a union between the detail_IDs of product_ID 1 and product_ID 4.  Since product_ID 1 has the intDescription_detail_IDs of 1 and 2, and product_ID 4 also has these detail_IDs.  2) 7 and 10 are description_IDs and I am trying to return the product_IDs.

Comment: ok got you now. Bit confused by the description.

Comment: @mrdnk sorry about the confusion.  I'm new to mysql and stackoverflow, so my descriptions are probably off.  I'll keep trying to get better!

Comment: No worries, its always hard to describe a problem that's in your head.

Comment: Since your new to mysql. I would suggest learning some naming conventions. 'tbl'  prefix for tables is mostly not used (we still use them where I work - for legacy reasons). But would use tblDescription (camel case). And prefix of type on a column, well I haven't seen that before. With databases you want to avoid column names with type. Personally my preference is for camel case over underscore (but that's a preference).

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I will definitely try to incorporate these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to @Strawberry’s suggestion with JOINs this can also be done using HAVING for filtering products that have (at least) the same number of rows with the same `intDescription_detail_ID`s as the product the search is done for:

```
SELECT intDescription_product_ID
FROM tbldescriptions t1
WHERE intDescription_detail_ID IN (
  SELECT intDescription_detail_ID
  FROM tbldescriptions t2
  WHERE t2.intDescription_product_ID = 1
  )
GROUP BY intDescription_product_ID
HAVING count(*) >= (
  SELECT count(intDescription_detail_ID)
  FROM tbldescriptions t3
  WHERE t3.intDescription_product_ID = 1
  )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce698/2

One should keep in mind though that HAVING is applied last, so that will select all products with at least *one* matching `intDescription_detail_ID` first, and filter the results based on the actual count afterwards – so depending on the size and characteristic of your data set that might not be the best performing solution.

Answer (score 1):

I should warn you by saying that I may have made a silly mistake here...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;

CREATE TABLE products(product_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,product_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO products VALUES
(1,'dresser'),
(2,'bookcase'),
(3,'table'),
(4,'chair');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_detail;

CREATE TABLE product_detail
(product_id INT NOT NULL
,detail_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(product_id,detail_id)
);

INSERT INTO product_detail VALUES
(1,1),
(1,2),
(2,1),
(2,2),
(2,6),
(3,1),
(3,3),
(3,4),
(4,1),
(4,2),
(4,7);


SELECT DISTINCT c.product_id 
  FROM product_detail a
  JOIN product_detail b
    ON b.product_id = a.product_id
   AND b.detail_id <> a.detail_id
  JOIN product_detail c
    ON c.product_id <> a.product_id
   AND c.detail_id = a.detail_id
  JOIN product_detail d 
    ON d.product_id = c.product_id
   AND d.detail_id = b.detail_id
 WHERE a.product_id = 1;

  +------------+
  | product_id |
  +------------+
  |          2 |
  |          4 |
  +------------+
```

Comment: I was playing with this and changed the product_id to 2 and found that the query matched on 1 and 4, but I was hoping that 2 would not find any matches since it's set of details (1, 2, and 6) did not have a match on any other products.